# Переписать драйвер с windows x32 на x64 очень сложно? Почему?

Tags: windows, драйвер, x86-64

Правда ли, что переписать какой-либо драйвер для той же винды очень сложно, если он для 32-ух разрядной системы, а нужно теперь на 64 разрядную? Несколько раз натыкался на данное высказывание. Но конкретно почему, сколько не искал, так и не нашел ответа.

Вот, допустим, мы знаем как сделать колесо. А теперь нам нужно колесо побольше (или поменьше). Просто применяем старые знания с новыми значениями. Разве не так?

В чем такая сильная разница, в чем различие (на уровне написания драйвера), что некоторые не могут этого сделать?

А может это всё и неправда и не так уж сложно?

Хочу подробностей каких-либо. Можно с кусочками кода на любом языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, все сложно, если не знаешь как. *"А может это всё и неправда и не так уж сложно?"* - такое тоже может быть, зависит от задачи.

При переходе на 64-bit надо учитывать моменты, перечисленные в [Porting Your Driver to 64-Bit Windows > Porting Issues Checklist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/hardware/ff559744(v=vs.85).aspx)